# Intuition behind similarity solution for Heat equation

Tags: heat-equation, dimensional-analysis

The heat equation is $$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}=\kappa\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}.$$ From this, one can look at dimensions on both sides, and conclude that the quantity $$\eta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\kappa t}}$$ is dimensionless. From here, it seems every source on the internet says "since $\eta$ is dimensionless, it says something about the system, so try a solution of the form ...", without deriving anything. Is there any way to get some information out of this without guessing? My question in particular was about the following: suppose $\theta=\alpha t^{-p}F(x,t)$, $\alpha$ is a constant; then show $F(x,t)$ is a function of $\eta$ only. I feel like the step that is skipped when websites guess the solution is the step that I am missing to answer my question.

Comment: Also now that I think about it - how do you normally show some $F$ is a function of some variable $x$ only, given a differential equation?

Comment: If $F$ is dimensionless, would this help to show anything?

Comment: It is important what the boundary conditions are! If they are not simply vanishing at infinity, then they necessarily introduce another scale into the problem and the solution will depend on the details of the boundary conditions, but in the limit of $t\to \infty$, the "memory" of the initial conditions are lost and one can show that the leading order solution is asymptotically equivalent to the similarity solution.

Comment: @Cyclone Ahh yes, that does make sense. I don't really recall this problem unfortunately, or where I got it from, so I don't know what the boundary conditions were